# Creating a "floating" top navigation like on zendesk.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, css-position

I'd like to create a "floating" top navigation like seen on [here](http://www.zendesk.com).

When scrolling down the page, the top navigation of course dissapears out of the browser window, but it comes back into the view, and stays on top all the way down.

I can see that the CSS is changing at the `div#nav-bar-content`, but I can't figure out when these styles are applied in JavaScript.

If someone has a pointer to how it can be achieved using jQuery, or where in the [Zendesk](http://www.zendesk.com) source code I can find an example of this, it would be great.

Thank you very much in advance!

Regards Kim

Comment: http://www.zendesk.com/wp-content/themes/zendesk-twentyeleven/js/script.js Look for: `bar    = $("#nav-bar-content"),
   offset = $("#nav-bar-anchor").offset().top,`

Comment: Thanks MetalFrog. That was just what I needed :) If you can convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: It's all good, you wanted a push, I gave one. I just searched the source of the page for ".js" and opened a few of the files to see where the nav binding was set up.

Answer (score 3):

You should reposition your menu on each `scroll` event.

```
<div class='menu'>Menu content</div>
```

---

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) // 20 - offset from the top
        $('.menu').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0'
        });
    else
        $('.menu').css({
            position: 'static'
        });
});
```

**UPDATE:** And the static solution using CSS:

```
div.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

Comment: Without the extra code from the detailed example you link to, this snippet does not function. What if that link goes down?